Modeling a graph for finance transactions
I'm modeling a graph to record a company's financial transactions.
I need to receive the following reports:

profit and loss statement
balance
account balances for each month

Could you please advise which graph model is right for me?
The most important question: where to store the date of each transaction - in the properties of nodes/edges or create nodes for each month?
I've googled a lot, but I don't have an answer yet.
